# Child, with min-height set to 100%, does not take up parent's height

Tags: css, reactjs

I currently have this setup

```
    <div style={{ height: "800px", backgroundColor: "red" }}>
      <div style={{ minHeight: "100%", backgroundColor: "orange" }}>
        <div style={{ minHeight: "100%", backgroundColor: "green" }}>
          This has content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

However, the green `div` is not taking up all the space of its orange parent.

[image]

I'm absolutely breaking my head over it, does anyone have any clue of why this is happening?
Do note, setting height to `100vh` is not a solution, it's a dirty hack.

You can find the working example at https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-hoover-23y8v?file=/src/App.js:67-333

Comment: percentage always refer to *height* and not min-height. The orange doesn't have a height defined

Comment: min-height with percentage value just work when the parent have absolute height. The parent div has not.